# WPF ListView Remove Border from Top and Sides of Headers

Tags: wpf, listview, header, controls, border

I am trying to create a borderless ListView/GridView.  The background of my screen is gray, but there is a think border over the headers and on the left of the farthest left header and the right of the farthest right header.  I have tried templating the header container style, and it will not remove them.  Is there any way to get ride of them?

```
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.4091"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderBorderBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderHoverBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderPressBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderGripper" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Right" Value="-9"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="0"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderOver" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0, 0, 0, 0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="7"/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="UpperHighlight" Fill="Transparent" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContent" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0,0,0,0" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="HeaderHoverBorder" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                            <Border x:Name="HeaderPressBorder" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                            <Canvas>
                                <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper" Style="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderGripper}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="HeaderBorder" Value="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderHoverBackground}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="HeaderHoverBorder" Value="#FF88CBEB"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="PART_HeaderGripper" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="HeaderBorder" Value="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderPressBackground}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="HeaderHoverBorder" Value="#FF95DAF9"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="HeaderPressBorder" Value="#FF7A9EB1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="#FFBCE4F9"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_HeaderGripper" Value="Hidden"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderContent" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Height" Value="Auto">
                                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Stuff}" Margin="0" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderOver}">
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader IsEnabled="False" Content="Sector" Background="Gray" Foreground="White" FontSize="30" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="0"/>

                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border Margin="0"
                                            Background="Gray"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="30"
                                                   Text="{Binding Sector}"
                                                   Foreground="White"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader IsEnabled="False" Content="Revenue" Background="Gray" Foreground="White" FontSize="30" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Gray"/>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border Margin="0"
                                            Background="Gray"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="30"
                                                   Text="{Binding Sector}"
                                                   Foreground="White"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @Binarus I have added code.  Thanks for taking a look.